# Where can I find a good CAML tutorial?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, caml-query, learning, tutorials

I am just starting to get my feet wet with SP Foundation 2010, and need to customize some web parts. I am looking for some CAML tutorials that go beyond what's on the MSDN site, and also include the SP configuration considerations to run various queries. I'm particularly interested in learning more about integrating JavaScript with CAML...I've heard that it can be done, but don't know to what extent, and have not seen any relevant samples. Suggestions?

Comment: A broad question like this must be made community wiki (if allowed)

Comment: @Anders Have the moderators made community-wiki available to OPs? According to meta, authors can't make something community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was helpful  - [Writing CAML Queries For Retrieving List Items from a SharePoint List](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list) and is fairly comprehensive.

Comment: broken link... the link will not work!

Comment: It's been a few years - try this link: 
http://mossknowledge.blogspot.com/2012/07/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving.html

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this tutorial. Hope this will help you in learning the CAML query basics.
[CAML Query tutorial for SharePoint](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/05/caml-query-tutorial-for-sharepoint.html)

Answer (score 1):

On MSDN you find a nice intro here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms426449.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [U2U CAML Builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx).

Comment: We  require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines. Better still, just link to the original source rather than via your blog.