# Tutorials CAML for Sharepoint

Tags: development

Have You know any CAML Tutorials ? At most i would like to find any Tutorial for U2U CAML Query Builder. **Please help**.

Comment: I found This topic Its very good:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34929/where-can-i-find-a-good-caml-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grzegors,

[U2U CAML Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) and [CAML Viewer](http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/), these softwares are written to make your life easy with CAML and you don't need to memorize these things :)...

Also a great tutorial [here](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list) which uses Calendar list, so this should help you!

Comment: And what does meandry in CAML {0} {1}

Comment: {0} {1}, where did you get this in CAML ??? :) Please paste the CAML so I can have a look!

Comment: `string DateOnlyQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq></Where>";
            string FullQuery = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Pracownik' /><Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
            string dateISO = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToLocalTime());`

Comment: I use [CodeCaml](http://nuget.org/packages/CodeCaml) all the time

Comment: {0}, {1} doesn't have any relation with CAML... I think its just used in [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx), see the details on link!

Comment: I know now why !!! :) :) **Thanks Arsalan Adam Khatri**